# Enable https in kibana 6.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

How to enable https in kibana? Followed the steps mentioned in this url :https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-https/64279/2 . but still i am getting "Not Secure" in browser. 
what i did?
1. download server.key and server.cer file
2. added entry in kibana.yml and enabled ssl

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So what's the actual problem with the certificate?

This is Chrome, right? Head to the developer tools: View -> Developer -> Developer Tools. Then hit the Security tab and view the details for the certificate. Here's the one for Stackoverflow.

[image]

If I had to guess I'd assume your certificate is not valid for localhost.

PS: Please add the details to your original question.